# Custom Build Activities

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

Can you create custom build activities or something similar in TFS 2008, or is that a new feature in TFS 2010?

I'm asking because I want to run silverlight automated tests via the build server:
http://pyxis-tech.com/blog/2011/01/24/how-to-run-silverlight-automated-tests-on-tfs-build-server/#comment-214

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New feature. TFS2008 didn't use workflow at all. You would need to use a custom task in MSBUILD.